# Says invalid column name rowid - ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql-server, select

This is my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestID ORDER BY CriticalAssessmentID DESC) AS rowid
FROM
    ApplicationCriticalityAssessment
```

This works perfectly fine and gives me incremental rowid's like 1, 2,3, 4 etc. for the same `requestID`.

When I want to select only rowid=1

```sql
SELECT
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestID ORDER BY CriticalAssessmentID DESC) AS rowid
FROM
    ApplicationCriticalityAssessment  
WHERE
    rowid = 1
```

Now this falters with an error

> Invalid column name rowid.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use column aliases in the `where` clause. One approach is to wrap it in another query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY RequestID
                                  ORDER BY CriticalAssessmentID DESC) 
                  AS rowid
        FROM   ApplicationCriticalityAssessment) t
WHERE  rowid = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a  subquery  or Cte

```
select * from (

select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by RequestID order by CriticalAssessmentID desc) as rowid
from ApplicationCriticalityAssessment  

)a
where  rowid=1
```